# 的に being used as "because"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Usually 的に making the proceeding noun into an adverb has usually been simple enough for me to understand, but the following sentence confused me:

> 容姿的にマスコミが持ち上げようとするのもわかるが

It feels here like it ought to be something like "I get that the mass media will flatter her **because** of her physical looks, but..."

But my brain can't seem to process this as making sense with 容姿的に as an adverb, since modifying 持ち上げよう or わかる with it doesn't make much sense, unless I'm completely misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I guess English "-wise" seems to come to have a similar meaning recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the correct way to parse it is:`〜的に〜だ` (so it doesn't modify the verb, it indicates what the topic relates to).

E.g. you can say 容姿的に無理だ、容姿的にちやほやされるタイプだろう、容姿的にちやほやしたくなる気持ちも分かる、容姿的にマスコミがちやほやしようとするのもわかるが、and also 容姿的にマスコミが持ち上げようとするのもわかるが